# Replace delimiter between non-digits - Redshift

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to execute a query to replace dot (.) with a comma (,) only in positions where the dot is between non-digits.

Table:

```
full_name 
LISADOR. COMPRIMIDO (16UN)
ALOPURINOL 1.0MG. COMPRIMIDO (30UN)
RILAN 40MG/ML. SOLUCAO NASAL (1UN DE 13ML)
DORENE 1.0MG. CAPSULA (30UN)
```

I am expecting this result:

```
full_name_new 
LISADOR, COMPRIMIDO (16UN)
ALOPURINOL 1.0MG, COMPRIMIDO (30UN)
RILAN 40MG/ML, SOLUCAO NASAL (1UN DE 13ML)
DORENE 1.0MG, CAPSULA (30UN)
```

To do this, I'm trying this regex:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(full_name, '(.*\D)\.(\D.*)', '\1,\2') as full_name_new
```

I tested this regex in Postgre and it worked, but in Redshift it returned the same column as the input, without the change.

Does anyone know what changes are needed in Redshift to get this result?

Comment: Dot between non-digits `(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(full_name, '(.*[^0-9])\\.([^0-9].*)', '\1,\2') as full_name_new
```

Your line didn't work because you didn't double escape `\\D`. See [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html). The `p` flag is likely also needed as [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html) specifies.